# iHome Mouse drivers for OS X

Tags: macos, mouse, driver

I have an iHome wireless 5 button laser mouse model iH-M130ZR and I can't find any drivers to be able to program the buttons. By default, left/right/scroll clicks work, but I can't get any response from the other buttons. Does anyone know of a program or drivers that will let me take advantage of these other buttons? Even to just be able to use the side buttons for back/forward in browsing would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard [good](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10376188-263.html) [things](http://www.macworld.com/reviews/product/412661/review/usb_overdrive_301.html) about [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com). While the name of the utility implies that it's USB-only, it also works for devices connected via Bluetooth.

Another possible option is [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/).

Comment: Note that USB Overdrive is not (yet) compatible with Lion.

Comment: I'm on High Sierra, 10.13.3, and USB Overdrive works GREAT!